# What is the analog of normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A^\dagger A = AA^\dagger$ then $A$ is said to be normal. But if $A^TA = AA^T$, does $A$ have a special name?

Comment: If $A$ is a real matrix then $A^TA=AA^T$ just means it is normal. The broader definition $A^*A=AA^*$ covers complex matrices.

Comment: Your "broader" definition is not broader in the same sense that 'hermitian" is not broader than 'symmetric'.

Comment: Note, though, that a normal real matrix may only be diagonalizable as a normal complex matrix, e.g., the rotation matrix
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $\theta$ not an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: "Real normal", maybe? I would just say "normal matrix" in both cases, actually

Comment: @Mohammed The concept that for real matrices is _called_ symmetric is in many instances generalized to "hermitian" instead of "symmetric" for complex matrices, because it behaves better.

Comment: @Mohammed there exist symmetric non-hermitian complex matrices, thus the notion "hermitian" is broader.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy and there exist, too, hermitian non-symmetric matrices